# combine all 3 $_post to 1 variable

Tags: php

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tedeee/846o03db/)

I wanted to combine all 3 `$_POST` to 1 variable but the month day wont show up, how come?

Here is the code:

```
<div id="register-birth-date">

  <input type="number" name="register-day" placeholder="DATE">

    <select id="register-month">
      <option value="00">Mouth</option>
      <option value="01">January</option>
      <option value="02">February</option>
      <option value="03">March</option>
      <option value="04">April</option>
      <option value="05">May</option>
      <option value="06">June</option>
      <option value="07">July</option>
      <option value="08">August</option>
      <option value="09">September</option>
      <option value="10">October</option>
      <option value="11">November</option>
      <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>

  <input type="number" name="   " placeholder="YEARS">

</div>
```

```
$air_user_registered_date = $_POST['register-day']."/".$_POST['register-month']."/".$_POST['register-years'];
```

Comment: Try to check month value with `die($_POST['register-month'])`.

Comment: you should post your html as well.

Comment: We don't know how this is possible if you don't show the html.

Comment: try to add to select attribute `name="register-month"`

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `name` attribute to both your `select box` for months and `input box` for years.

```
<div id="register-birth-date">

  <input type="number" name="register-day" placeholder="DATE" />

  <select name="register-month" id="register-month">
    <option value="00">Mouth</option>
    <option value="01">January</option>
    <option value="02">February</option>
    <option value="03">March</option>
    <option value="04">April</option>
    <option value="05">May</option>
    <option value="06">June</option>
    <option value="07">July</option>
    <option value="08">August</option>
    <option value="09">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
  </select>

  <input type="number" name="register-years" placeholder="YEARS" />
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/846o03db/1/)

Comment: yeah, that'll do it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Date Text box given the `name` of `"register-day"`.

Month Select box give the `name` of `"register-month"`.

Year Text box give `name` of `"register-years"`.